# Pure virtual methods in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, virtual-functions

What is the ideologically correct way of implementing *pure virtual methods* in Python?

Just raising `NotImplementedError` in the methods?

Or is there a better way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While it's not uncommon to see [people using `NotImplementedError`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0220__Class/Creatingaclasshierarchywithanabstractbaseclass.htm), some will argue that the "proper" way to do it (since python 2.6) is using a **Abstract Base Class**, through the [`abc` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html):

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__=ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_method():
        pass
```

---

There's two main (potential) advantages in using `abc` over using `NotImplementedError`.

Firstly, You won't be able to instantiate the abstract class (without needing `__init__` hacks):

```
>>> MyAbstractClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyAbstractClass with abstract methods my_abstract_method
```

Secondly, you won't be able to instantiate any subclass that doesn't implement all abstract methods:

```
>>> class MyConcreteClass(MyAbstractClass):
...     pass
... 
>>> MyConcreteClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MyConcreteClass with abstract methods my_abstract_method
```

---

[Here's a more complete overview on abstract base classes](http://dbader.org/blog/abstract-base-classes-in-python)